# Prove that series with non summable coefficients do not converge in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\{e_i\}_i$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $||e_i||=1$ and such that every $x \in X$ can be written as $ x = \sum_{i=1} ^\infty \lambda_i e_i$ with a sequence $ \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty |\lambda_i| < \infty $.

If we further assume that these representations by absolutely summable sequences of coefficients are unique, can we show that if $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty |\lambda_i| = \infty$, the corresponding sequence $x_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i e_i$ does not converge in $X$?

Note: the uniqueness condition is
$$\forall x\in X \colon |\{\lambda_i\in \mathbb{R}^\infty: (x=\sum\lambda_ie_i) \wedge( \sum |\lambda_i|<\infty )\}|=1$$ not $$\forall x\in X \colon |\{\lambda_i\in \mathbb{R}^\infty : x=\sum\lambda_ie_i \}|=1\wedge (x=\sum\lambda_ie_i\Rightarrow \sum |\lambda_i|<\infty )$$

Comment: I deleted my answer, fixed the grammar in your question, and pointed out why the question isn't as trivial as I mistakenly assumed in my first attempt at answering it. Let me know if I captured the intent of your question correctly, then I can make an another attempt

Answer (score 0):

By the open mapping theorem, the obvious bijection $\ell^1\to X$ has a continuous inverse. Thus the sequence $x_n$ in question does not converge.